# Winform use WebBrowser open website, and get data back from it

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, winforms

I'm now developing a windows application in c#, and also building a website using asp.net in c#.

(Keep it simple)
I want the user to open a website inside the application. It will be a textbox in a website, and the user will enter a string, clicks the button on the website. 
Then the windows application will get the string that the user enters in the website.

```
    protected void passDataBack(object sender, EventArgs e)  // in website
    {
        string str = TextBox1.Text;
        // pass str to windows applcation
    }
```

The code above is when user enters string in the website, and clicks button to send it back.

```
    private void browseWebsite(object sender, EventArgs e)  // in windows application
    {
        var Url = "http://localhost:55389/Homepage.aspx";
        myWebBrowser.Navigate(Url);

        string ans = "";
        // so I want ans to be the string user inputs in textbox(str)
    }
```

Then the str user inputs in the textbox should be stored in "ans"

I hope I explain it clearly, hope someone can help, thanks so much !

Comment: Could you explain what the issue is that you are having? You've explained your application but you haven't actually asked a questioned or described your issue.

Comment: I wrote an answer based on using the ObjectForScripting property, but then realised that you're not using any JavaScript - when you say "in website", you're actually talking about server side asp.net code.  This can't talk (directly) to the winforms app.  Does it have to be server side, or are you open to using JavaScript?